# Search filter using JSON to populate in real time

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on a search function for my site which will search through a JSON Object using a regular expression. What I am going for is: as the user searches, the results display in real time, almost like Google does with their search results.

Unfortunately I do not have any source code for this as I don't even know where to start.

Does anyone know how this can be done? Or any reference sites which would explain this to me?

Comment: `I am working on a search function for my site` - what have you done so far?

Comment: When people don't know where to start, neither do we with our answers. Please be specific with what you don't know how to do. Always do plenty of research before coming here for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work on breaking down your problem into its component parts, and then tackling each point. For example, from the data I have one could break the above problem down like this:

1. Add a keypress listener to the search bar or listen to a click event on its submit button to trigger a Javascript search method.
2. In the search method, read the value from the search field.
3. Iterate through your JSON, comparing the strings in the JSON against the search value, and file an array of matches as you see fit.
4. Iterate through the matches and use Javascript to draw new DOM elements as search results, or iterate through the existing DOM element and hide / show them as appropriate.

---

By breaking down your problem above, you can draw some more concrete problems that need solving:

1. How do you listen for a keypress or click event on a DOM element?
2. How do you call a Javascript method from one of these events?
3. How do you read the value of your search field?
4. How do you iterate through a JSON object?
5. How do you dynamically draw new DOM elements based on an array of values?

All of the above questions already have answers on Stack Overflow which you can search and look up.